# use both url param and query param on one react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

can we use use both URL param and query params on the same path like router path="/restaurants/:id?lat=50" and get both value on router?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
For url params:

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const {id} = useParams();
```

For query params: [DOCS LINK](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

Comment: both useParams and query param same time? what is the path of the router?

Comment: The path should be `/restaurants/:id` in your example.